# Requirement to use "за"

Tags: грамматика

How are these sentences different from each other? (The flight will take 6 hours) :

~Полёт / Перелёт займёт шесть часов

~Мы долетим *за* шесть часов

It takes around 3 hours to make borscht.

Чтобы приготовить борщ, нужно примерно три часа.

I erroneously assumed that I'd have to say *za* in the first sentence too. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In sentence 1 *шесть часов* is a direct object after **transitive** verb, so similarly to the English version with 'it will take us 6 hours', it doesn't take *any preposition*. Same with the last Russian sentence: "нужно (затратить - omitted)" reveals transitivity resulting in no preposition.

Answer (score 0):

Here, `за` is like English `in`.  Like `in`, `за` presents only after the verb specifying the action.

- We will do it **in** three hours. (Мы сделаем это **за** три часа.)
- It will take three hours to do it. (Literally: Займёт три часа сделать это. 
  Better: Это займёт три часа. )
- One can cook borscht **in** three hours - борщ можно приготовить **за** три часа.
- One can cook borscht **in** about three hours - борщ можно приготовить примерно **за** три часа (часа **за** три - the stress here should be on **за**).
- It takes about three hours to cook borscht - чтобы приготовить борщ, нужно примерно три часа (около трёх часов, часа три); приготовление борща занимает около трёх часов.

Comment: Sorry but your English examples with 'for' are wrong. -1

Comment: @A.Toumantsev - hope it is better now.

Comment: I'd be interested in comments from English natives as my English is not perfect (although quite good). I would use 'within' here rather than 'in'...

Comment: I'd be interested in HEARING ANY comments from ANY English natives OUT THERE, SINCE/as my English is not perfect BY ANY MEANS (although IT'S STILL quite good THOUGH). I would use 'within' here rather than / INSTEAD OF "in"

Comment: I don't see why you changed what he wrote?You just made it longer and added no real value)

Comment: @VCH250 - who changed what who wrote?

Comment: @ user31264 Not you. I had штефан and his corrections in mind.